# Oracle Apex hide version

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

In Oracle Apex, is there a way to keep technology profiler tool to extract the versions? For example, RequireJS, jQuery, jQuery Migrate, jQuery UI. Once the profiler run, these technologies should not be displayed on the said profiler.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but - what is that "technology profiler tool"? Is it part of Apex (i.e. built into it), or is it your own (or 3rd party) application? If former, I've never heard of it. If latter, then you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: since most of the information is readly available to the browser it would be quite diffcult to hide which libraries it is downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not likely a way to block a profiler tool from identifying the versions of the libraries and such because they are built right into the libraries. For example, running this in the browser console will output the version of jQuery:

```
console.log( 'You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery );
```

Unless Oracle modifies the libraries (which seems highly unlikely) to remove any abilities to return the version of the library, there's not much you can do. If someone was very determined, they could still just download the javascript, css, etc. files from your server and compare them against the known releases of the libraries to match them to a version.